# Getting listview ID name

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm passing a listview in to an onselect but theres a couple of ways it's called from different listviews. So i'm trying to work out which listview is being clicked.

I thought I could do the following however the string thats returned is like com.myapp.tool/id/32423423c (type thing) instead of lvAssets.

Here is what I've got:

```
@Override
public void onNumberRowSelect(ListView listview, clsNameID stat) {

    if(listview.getAdapter().toString().equals("lvGenericAssets")){

    } else if(listview.getAdapter().toString().equals("lvAssets")){

    } else {
        Functions.ShowToolTip(getApplicationContext(), 
                              listview.getAdapter().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Emil Adz said in first, you can get the id of your list by calling `list.getId();`

Then use `String idList = getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);` and you will be able to get the **name** of the id you have given to your list

Comment: strangely, I gave the same answer (the id part), 10 minutes earlier.

Comment: The OP want a way to distinct hist ListViews, this could be done using the id's as well. No one says you didn't know that, but some does says that there is no point in giving the same answer if it was already given, just to earn some rep. The name addition is pointless in this case, just to make your answer different then mine.

Comment: I gave you the reason, why I did it. You instead of acknowledge that what you did is wrong, made a sarcastic remark: "WOW amazing...". You can remove the id part, and I will remove the downvote. I think it's only fair.

Comment: @EmilAdz Answer edited. Sorry If you think I "stole" you the answer, it was not the goal =).

Comment: I don't think you did, I think that there should be some respect and credit given here to the effort people put in their answers. And if an answer already was given, it should not be given again to earn some rep.

Answer (score 1):

Why wont you just use: `list.getId();` if you defined it in the XML file then you should define there an id for you `ListView`.

If you are doing this from code then you can use the `list.setId();` to first set it's id.

Another thing you can do is to add a `Tag` to your `listView`:  `list.setTag("list1");`
and latter on distinct this `listView` using the Tag: `list.getTag();`